# Developing Touch over ethernet

Tags: ethernet

Is this *ever* going to be possible? We have voice, image, data, etc..over ethernet. Is Touch over ethernet possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the strides being made in Brain Computer Interfaces (e.g. controlling computers with nothing more than neural impulses), it's only logical to conclude that one day we'll be able to "reverse the stream" and have computers send the impulses to our brain that we can then interpret as touch, sight, hearing, taste, and smell. Who knows, it's quite possible that it has been done already and we are all dreamers in a digital world.

How's that for a mind frack?

Comment: I know my answer might be interpreted as if I'm mocking you...but I'm definitely not. Besides the matrix, check out Surrogates (with Bruce Willis) for an interesting view on where technology may lead us.